# Angular2+ visualize component hierarchy/template hierarchy

Tags: angular, analytics

Is there a plugin or a program that takes in a angular2+ application and draws component hierarchy and template hierarchy.

I would like to see the overall structure of my app, but I can't seem to find anything that can visualize it. I found [this](https://github.com/compodoc/ngd) but this only gived dependency hierarchy. I also need the see what template uses what other templates and how are the components and services connected to each other. It would be a really nice way to draw border between potential modules and to re-organize the project structure to be more clean.

Comment: I don't think this question would be related to Angular : it is used in web browsers for SPA, but what you're asking is to map a folder of your filesystem. Maybe you should instead look for IDE plugins or Typescript extensions ?

Comment: Maybe. Im not fully sure what could do this job. I have not yet found a way to get this.Its more complex than pure typescript extnesion, since it alse needs to be able to understand angular syntax with the templates and teplates within templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Augury is an excellent tool available as a Chrome Browser Extension that lets you also visualize component tree structure in Angular. It has many other features that can help you get more insight into your application and optimize push strategies and module loading. Augury wires with the standard Chrome Developer Tools and it has exactly all the features you asked for. You can install it from the Chrome Web Store for free and it's an open source solution built and maintained in cooperation by Angular team and Rangle.io so you can expect it to be up to date most of the time.

Comment: Well it does what i want, but not exactly, but close enought that i might be able to use it :D. I was hoping for a tool that can analyse the app folder of the project and create the graph/diagram from that.

Comment: Thats the best one there is since its supported by the angular team itself.

Comment: The one that i would want, would be combination of this and the one i found. That would be the best. But its good enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 tools that I can suggest:

1. https://compodoc.app/
2. https://github.com/mgechev/ngrev

Both helps you visualize your Angular app.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33287537)